# R: How to displayed range in Bar chart?

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, plotly, bar-chart

Try to generate Bar chart same as excel but is it possible in R?
Want to displayed total number of weekly order.count by user with start and end date of week.

```
User            Due_date            Status  

a               02-10-2017          Complete
b               02-02-2017          Ordered
a               02-08-2017          Complete
c               02-08-2017          Complete
a               02-08-2017          Ordered
s               02-06-2017          Complete
c               02-06-2017          Complete
s               02-06-2017          Ordered
b               02-06-2017          Ordered
c               02-11-2017          Complete
a               02-11-2017          Ordered
s               02-11-2017          Ordered
c               02-01-2017          Complete
s               02-01-2017          Ordered
b               02-01-2017          Complete
b               02-10-2017          Complete
```

Try to generate report but not displayed range which is displayed in excel,
Please check the code and attached screenshot.

```
library(lubridate)
Data$Week_Due = (ceiling_date(Data$Due.Date, "week") +  ifelse(weekdays(Data$Due.Date) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), 5,-2))

library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(Data,  aggregatorName = "Count",  rows = "User",  cols = c("Week_Due","User","Status"),  width = "100%",  height = "500px",rendererName = "Bar Chart")
```

[Click here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z00t5.png)

Comment: Are the "dates" in your `Due_date` column really dates? That is, does R think that they are dates?

Comment: @Edward Yes, it is dates based on that dates identify status in which week which user get order completed and remaining.

Comment: What is the result of typing: `class(Data$Due.Date)`?

Comment: result of typing: ```class(Data$Due.Date)``` =>  "Date"

Comment: From your question it is not entirely clear, where you're stuck - anyway, to get something similar to the excel chart, this might provide some ideas: ```ggplot(Data, aes(x = Due_date)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 7) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d-%b")```

Comment: @WolfgangArnold  I want to displayed range of week which displayed at X in attached screenshot of excel. is that possible through R?

Comment: @WolfgangArnold Thanks, `ggplot(Data, aes(x = Due_date)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 7) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%d-%b")` 
this is great but this chart displayed as report and in this report given multiple filters like user and status, so this will not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - here's a bit more elaborate example that should be closer to what you want to achieve: for modifying labels on x-axis to show date ranges you need to put in a simple function. And, I'm using `breaks` instead `date_breaks` in order to move the tick marks more or less in the middle under the bars of the histogram.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Due_date)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 7) + 
    scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(Data$Due_date), max(Data$Due_date), by = 7),
        labels = function(x) paste0(format(x, "%d-%m-%Y"), ", ", format(x+7, "%d-%m-%Y"))) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```